# Reading Contents of an Open Win32 Window

Tags: c#, python, node.js

I'm not sure how to go about this, I'd like to capture text from an open window in a Windows Environment, such as something simple like NotePad.

Is there a way to use Node, Python, or C# to accomplish this? Are there any articles or Docs in any languages that apply to what I'm trying to do you know of?

Ultimately, I want to capture the text content, and then manipulate it in the program, and return the modified content.

Comment: That entirely depends on how the program works.  Notepad is easy; other programs are not.  Consider using the accessibility APIs,

Comment: If you have Visual Studio installed take a look to Spy++, it will give you a good idea on how to do it (Spy->Find window).